# Async Await new instance of VueJS gulp/babel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, async-await

I am stuck with an async await implementation on VueJS using babel and transform-runtime plugin.
Babel seems to work correctly. The chunk has been created and correctly loaded by the browser. It contains the correct JS code obtained from the Ticker.vue component, but it is not rendered on the page. no 404 no JS errors in the console.
It looks like the "new Vue()" is not running at all and I can't find any similar issue or solution in VueJS documentation.

Any idea on what could be wrong on it?

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "ie >= 10"]
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import", 
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "polyfill": false,
      "helper": false,
      "regenerator": true,
      "moduleName": "babel-runtime" 
    }]]
}
```

package.json

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
"babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1"
```

current working implementation of vue instance

```
import Ticker from './components/ticker.vue';
const ticker = document.getElementById('ticker-vue-stackst');

if (ticker) {
    new Vue({
        el: ticker,
        render: h => h(Ticker)
    })
}
```

new implementation with async await

```
async function renderTicker() {
    const ticker = document.getElementById('ticker-vue-container');
    console.log(ticker);

    if (ticker !== null) {
        const Ticker = await import('./components/ticker.vue');
        console.log(Ticker)
        new Vue({
            el: ticker,
            render: h => h(Ticker)
        })
    }
}

renderTicker();
```

gulp task

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path');
const PluginError = require('plugin-error');
const log = require('fancy-log');


module.exports = function (gulp, projectConfig, isProd) {
    const plugins = []
    let theSourcemap

    if (isProd) {
        plugins.push(new UglifyJsPlugin())
        plugins.push(
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            })
        )
        theSourcemap = false
    } else {
        theSourcemap = 'source-map'
        plugins.push(
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
            })
        )
    }
    const webpackMode = isProd ? 'production' : 'development';
    gulp.task('webpack', function (callback) {
        webpack({
            resolve: {
                modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')]
            },
            resolveLoader: {
                modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')]
            },
            entry: {
                vue: `${projectConfig.src.vue}boot.js`
            },
            mode : webpackMode,
            devtool: theSourcemap,
            plugins: plugins,
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.vue$/,
                        loader: 'vue-loader',
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        options: {
                            loaders: {
                                js: {
                                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        extends: path.join(process.cwd(), './.babelrc')
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.js$/,
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        options: {
                            extends: path.join(process.cwd(), './.babelrc')
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.scss$/,
                        use: [
                          'vue-style-loader',
                          'css-loader',
                          'sass-loader'
                        ]
                      }
                ],
            },
            output: {
                path: path.resolve(`${projectConfig.dest.scripts}/`),
                publicPath: '/build/_client/scripts/',
                filename: '[name].js',
                chunkFilename: "[id].vue.js"
            }
        }, function(err, stats) {
            if (err) {
                throw new PluginError('webpack', err)
            }

            log('webpack', stats.toString({
                colors: true
            }))

            callback()
        })
    })

}
```

Comment: You changed `if (ticker) {` to `if(ticker !== null)`... but I doubt that's the issue.

Comment: `const Ticker = await import('./components/ticker.vue');` seems ... wrong. Why are you `await`'ing `import` ?

Comment: I am awaiting the import for loading the script only when needed. It's called dynamic import and it's working just fine with ES6 modules,but it looks like Vue has something to say about it

Comment: Interesting... hadn't heard dynamic import() was up and coming really!